# A another ADO.Net OData subject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, ado.net, odata

I got an OData Service and i'm trying to load the relation between the entities. For exemple i got a Ponderation and TypePonderation entites.

So on my client side i want to obtaint the typePonderation of each ponderation:

```
var ctx = new PonderationEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:7010/RDPPublication.svc"));
var query3 = ctx.Ponderation.Expand("TypePonderation");
```

But when i look in TypePonderation, i got a null reference, the typePonderation is not loaded.

However, if i use ctx.LoadProperty(VARIABLE, "TypePonderation");

```
var query4 = ctx.Ponderation;

            foreach (var VARIABLE in query4.ToList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE.CodeFonds);

                ctx.LoadProperty(VARIABLE, "TypePonderation");

                Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE.TypePonderation.Code);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

I got the TypePonderation with my ponderation.

What is this error ? Why Expand does not load my relation but LoadProperty does it ?

Here is the code for de Context (I use a edmx file) so the code is autogenerated.

Entitie : Ponderation
    namespace CDP.RDP.DataAccess.Publication
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

```
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class Ponderation
    {
        public System.Guid PonderationID { get; set; }
        public string CodeFonds { get; set; }
        public string CodePortefeuille { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> TypePonderationID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Periode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Ponderation1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreation { get; set; }
        public string CreePar { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> ReequilibragePubId { get; set; }

        public virtual TypePonderation TypePonderation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entitie TypePonderation

```
namespace CDP.RDP.DataAccess.Publication
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    [Serializable()]
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class TypePonderation
    {
        public TypePonderation()
        {
            this.Ponderation = new HashSet<Ponderation>();
        }

        public System.Guid TypePonderationID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreation { get; set; }
        public string CreePar { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ponderation> Ponderation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the context :

```
namespace CDP.RDP.DataAccess.Publication
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class PonderationEntities : DbContext
    {
        public PonderationEntities()
            : base("name=PonderationEntities")
        {
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<TypePonderation> TypePonderation { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ponderation> Ponderation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer to my problem. I order to make it work, i need to include my relation in the WCF Data Service.

I juste add this line in the OnStartProcessingRequest Methode :

```
CurrentDataSource.Ponderation.Include("TypePonderation").ToList();
```

And with that line i able to work with the Expand method on my client side.

Here is my code :

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class RDPPublication : DataService<CDP.RDP.DataAccess.Publication.RDPEntities>
    {
        //private IRDPPublicationServiceV2 _rdpPublicationService;

        public RDPPublication()
        {
            //_rdpPublicationService = UIUnityRegistry.GetInstance().Resolve<IRDPPublicationServiceV2>();
        }

        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            config.MaxExpandCount = 300;
            config.MaxExpandDepth = 300;
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead  | EntitySetRights.WriteMerge | EntitySetRights.WriteReplace);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }

        protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
        {
            base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);

            CurrentDataSource.Ponderation.Include("TypePonderation").ToList();
        }
    }
```

Hoping that this will help someone later

Anthony